# function on structure sheaf and its values at points

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, localization, ringed-spaces

I have some trouble understanding the concept of a function in Vakil's lecture notes.

First, let $X = Spec(A)$ for some ring $A$. A function $f$ is a section in $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$, thus an element of the ring. The value of a function at a point $p \in Spec(A)$ is an element in $A_p$. Now how can I evaluate $f(p)$ ?

Somehow it seems that $f(p) = 0$ iff $f \in p$.

Is $f(p)$ just the image of $f$ under the map $A \to A_p$ ?

Further, Vakil writes  3.2.12 that a function vanishes everywhere iff it is nilpotent.
Which is equivalent to it being in all prime ideals. But that doesn't mean that the element $f$ itself is zero. Is that correct ?

Comment: Everything you've written is correct

Comment: No, not everything is correct here - you want the image of $f$ in the **residue field** at $p$, or the image of $f$ under the composite map $A\to A_p \to A_p/p_p=k(p)$. But most of what you've written is correct!

Comment: Thanks alot guys ! @KReiser So you are taking the localised ring $A_p$, with $p_p$ as a prime ideal and forming the quotient ? And the last map is also the reason why $f(p) = 0$ iff $f \in p$ right ? But I only understand why if $f \in p$ we get that $f(p) = 0$.

Comment: The kernel of that composite map is just $p$. One way to see that is to write the composite map as $A\to A/p\to (A/p)_p = A_p/p_p$. (Or you can prove directly that the kernel is $p$.)